# Receiving "Invalid_Request" response from Google-DistanceMatrix api in VBA

Tags: google-distancematrix-api

I'm sending an XML Request to the google-distancematrix api with a string that looks like:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/xml?origin=Grafton,+VA&destination=Yorktown,+VA&key=myKey
```

and am getting the following back:

`<DistanceMatrixResponse>
   <status>INVALID_REQUEST</status>
  </DistanceMatrixResponse>`

I'm obviously doing something wrong when formatting the request string, any recommendations?

Answer (score 4):

turns out the syntax should be "origins" and "destinations" (plural) instead of "origin" and "destination"